# NACA Profile Approximation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

Is anyone aware of any research that explores the characteristics of [symmetrical NACA rudder profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA_airfoil) that are approximated using polygonal cross sections with few vertices (<20 per face) e.g.

[image: Image courtesy of Aerotoolbox]

Comment: Can you give more information on the question?

Comment: Boat rudders sometimes use NACA profiles such as 0012. I am wondering if this or similar symetric NACA curved profiles can be approximated. This would produce a chined effect down the side of the rudder as the curved surface is approximated with multiple vertical faces. It's a construction detail.

Comment: Might this question be better suited for [Engineering.SE]?

Comment: Interested in lift calculation for such profiles at small angles. Assumed here would be best place?